# Multithreaded merge-sort algorithm in Clojure

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, sorting, clojure

I need to write implementation of merge-sort algorithm in Clojure in single thread and using parallelism options with 2, 4, 8, 16, and 32 threads.
Program will read large collection of integers (1 million) from text file and put them into a list for sorting.
I am very newbie on Clojure and functional programming at all.
I've just written code for reading file ...

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)
(defn get-lines [fname]
  (with-open [r (reader fname)]
    (doall (map read-string (line-seq r)))))
(def numbers (get-lines "numbers.dat"))
```

... and found single thread implementation.
But I can't realize parallel algorithm. It seems to be beyond me.
Could anybody help me?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anybody is looking for...

```
(use 'clojure.java.io)

(defn get-lines [fname]
  (with-open [r (reader fname)]
    (doall (map read-string (line-seq r)))))

(def numbers (get-lines "numbers.dat"))

(defn merge-lists [left right]
  (loop [head [] L left R right]
    (if (empty? L) (concat head R)
    (if (empty? R) (concat head L)
    (if (> (first L) (first R))
      (recur (conj head (first R)) L (rest R))
      (recur (conj head (first L)) (rest L) R))))))

(defn naive-merge-sort [list]
  (if (< (count list) 2) list
    (apply merge-lists
      (map naive-merge-sort
        (split-at (/ (count list) 2) list)))))

(defn parallel-merge-sort-2 [list]
  (if (< (count list) 2) list
    (apply merge-lists
      (pmap naive-merge-sort
        (split-at (/ (count list) 2) list)))))

(defn parallel-merge-sort-4 [list]
  (if (< (count list) 2) list
    (apply merge-lists
      (pmap parallel-merge-sort-2
        (split-at (/ (count list) 2) list)))))

(defn parallel-merge-sort-8 [list]
  (if (< (count list) 2) list
    (apply merge-lists
      (pmap parallel-merge-sort-4
        (split-at (/ (count list) 2) list)))))

(defn parallel-merge-sort-16 [list]
  (if (< (count list) 2) list
    (apply merge-lists
      (pmap parallel-merge-sort-8
        (split-at (/ (count list) 2) list)))))

(defn parallel-merge-sort-32 [list]
  (if (< (count list) 2) list
    (apply merge-lists
      (pmap parallel-merge-sort-16
        (split-at (/ (count list) 2) list)))))
```

naive-merge-sort is single threaded implementation. parallel implementations breaks input list into 2-32 chunks which are sorted using naive-merge-sort.

Answer (score 0):

That does sound a lot like a homework assignment (as a commenter said), so I'm hesitant to provide a detailed answer. I can tell you that you'll want to look into different types of concurrency in Clojure. In order from simplest to most complex, some approaches you might want to consider for this problem are pmap, futures, and core.async. I suggest taking a look at the [basic docs for pmap](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pmap), at *Clojure For the Brave and True*'s chapters on [concurrency](http://www.braveclojure.com/concurrency/) and [core.async](http://www.braveclojure.com/core-async/), and at clojure.org's [page about concurrency](http://clojure.org/about/concurrent_programming)